# What is canonical r squared?

Tags: regression, r-squared, canonical-correlation

I know r-squared is the the percent of variance explained by a model. I am currently reading materials about canonical correlation and found a new concept "canonical r squared". The material does not explain this concept. So what does this "canonical r squared" mean and how it is calculated? Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide references, authors, and context for where you've encountered this?

Comment: I guess it just squared canonical correlation, isn't it?

Comment: @ttnphns Yes it seems to be just the squared canonical correlation. So many confusing concepts in statistical models.

Comment: It is the canonical correlation, squared: Reference: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1207/s15327752jpa8401_09